# DLLs Missing From Project Output Directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have the following Solution structure:

```
Solution.sln
--LibProject1
--LibProject2 (References LibProject1)
--WCFProject  (References LibProject2)
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that when I build `WCFProject`, the DLL corresponding to `LibProject1` is not added to the `WCFProject` output directory. For some reason it is not adding project sub-references.

My question is: Where could I have screwed the project files for this to happen? Is there any option I'm missing in the csproj or sln file?

Thanks!

P.D.: I'm using VS2012 Ultimate. Also, I already checked Copy Local is true for all projects.

Comment: did you add a project reference?

Comment: Are all projects configured to build under Build -> Configuration Management?

Comment: I think this is actually default behavior, only direct references for projects get included in the output.

Comment: Yes, I added a project reference and all projects are set to build. When I build LibProject2 it includes LibProject1 on its output.
@LukeMcGregor: How do I override this behavior? And I have my doubts about this. I don't remember this behavior from the past.

Comment: heh sorry, it was one of those "are you sure it's on?" questions :p

Comment: In the past ive just refed lib1 from WCFProject and the problem goes away. Ive never really looked too closely at why

Comment: I know the problem would go away by adding a direct reference, but that's not the idea. In some cases the reference tree goes quite deep, top level projects can't reference all assemblies used by all referenced projects.

Comment: I totally agree, the way ive always looked at it is that the end app is an aggregation of all that stuff anyway so while its annoying to reference everything it actually makes some sense

Comment: Besides this only occurs with a specific project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this figured out. Apparently, LibProject2 was not using any classes from LibProject1, hence, VS would not copy the DLL to the WCFProject output directory. As soon as classes from LibProject1 was consumed by LibProject2, the DLL was copied.

There you go, one day wasted over VS default behavior. u_u